# Creaky Cruise Control - 99 Ford Taurus Sedan

Tags: ford, taurus, cruise-control

I had been hearing creaking noises in the front of my car for awhile and it seemed like it was when applying the brake. I had had my brakes adjusted recently, so I assumed it was related.

However, today I was driving and turned on the cruise control and heard the same creaking sound (just a brief, single creak and not loud). I turned off the cruise control on the steering wheel and heard it again. This time I did not have my foot on the brake. I tested turning on and off the cruise control, and sure enough it creaked every time it was switched on or off. So it has nothing to do with the brakes after all.

I have no understanding of the mechanics involved in cruise control. What could be creaking?

I use my cruise control all the time, even at slow speeds. But I make sure not to use it going uphill or in bad weather. I'm always turning it on and off, though...